# useState reloads even though the values are the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I tested this a few times and I can't figure out why useState will reload, in all the tutorials and guides online, setState if the value is the same it should not cause a component re-render

My code is like this:

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState([]);
setOrder([500, 400, 400, 450]);
setOrder([500, 400, 400, 450]); //this causes react to rerender although the items and sequence are the same
```

I don't want it to re-render because each time the "order" array is changed, an API call is being made, but I only want it to call the API if the values or sequences are actually different

I tried disabling and enabling react StrictMode, and but it still rerender. I don't know why other people video it does not seem to rerender

Comment: This will because reference is changing

Comment: See [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)

Comment: array is a non-primitive data type. if you `console.log([] === [])`, you will get `false`.

Comment: How do I make the reference the same or change to a primitive data type?

Comment: you just [compare the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) before setting the state.

Answer (score 3):

It's rerendering because the new value is not equal to the previous value. It's a new array. `useState` compares values by identity but you can compare by any definition of equality you wish in your code.

In this case shallow element equality would make sense.

```
function elementsEqual(a, b) {
  return a.length === b.length && a.every((_, index) => a[index] === b[index]);
}
```

Then in your callbacks instead of passing in the new value as is `setOrder(newOrder)`, pass a function that returns the old value if it's equal to the new otherwise the new value.

```
setOrder(prevValue => elementsEqual(prevValue, newOrder) ? prevValue : newOrder);
```

Now your component will only rerender when the elements of `order` change.

Comment: This does not work

setOrder(prevValue => elementsEqual(prevValue, obj[0].departments["sales"].map(f=> f.userId)) ? prevValue : obj[0].departments["sales"].map(f=> f.userId));

Comment: It still refreshes every single time even though obj is constant

Comment: I cannot help you with problems you haven't provided information about. Sounds like your code has additional problems on top of what you described in this question.